# uploading image in facebook

Tags: iphone, ios

While uploading image in facebook wall, image is not at all getting on the wall.
I tried:

```
[[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"facebook.Users.setStatus" params:
            params dataParam:UIImagePNGRepresentation(img)];
```

to no avail.

Comment: other than Sharekit any solution?

Comment: On changing to @"facebook.photos.upload" images uploading but in the album without params.What i want is it should post with text(params)on the facebook wall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images will get into your photo Album and information about it on the wall.

```
NSMutableDictionary *params =[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Testmessage", @"message", imageData, @"picture", nil];

[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"/me/photos" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using Sharekit....

Try this code...

```
 -(void)shareOnFacebook {   
        //take screenshot
           UIImage *image = "Your image";

       //for debug purpose the image can be stored to photo album
       //UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);

         SHKItem *fbItem = [SHKItem image:image title:@"Check out my Image!"];
        [SHKFacebook shareItem:fbItem];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sharekit you can try following code:

```
-(IBAction)btnSendToFacebookPressed:(id)sender
{
            NSString *var = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"IMAGE_INDEX"];//This line may not be useful to you...

            NSString *imageIndex = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:var ofType:@"jpg"];

            SHKItem *item = [SHKItem image:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imageIndex] title:@"Your Title"];
            [NSClassFromString(@"SHKFacebook") performSelector:@selector(shareItem:) withObject:item];

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it using Sharekit.

Add Sharekit framework to your project.

Change the setting from shkconfig.h file.

pass the key which you can generate from facebook->developer->apps->create new app->generate keys  pass it to shkconfig.h

```
-(IBAction) tryItOnFb:(id)sender
{

     SHKItem *item = [SHKItem image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YES.png"]title:@"FB Test"];
     [NSClassFromString(@"SHKFacebook") performSelector:@selector(shareItem:) withObject:item];
}
```